# Which is correct - Shantanu or Shaantanu?

Tags: mahabharata, sanskrit, etymology

In the Mahabharata book by Gorakhpur press, the name is given as Shaantanu (शान्तनुः), but I've also heard his name as Shantanu (शन्तनुः). Is there a correct version?
For the name शन्तनुः, the derivation can be given as शं तनोति इति शन्तनुः - He who spreads auspiciousness.

Is there a derivation for the name शान्तनुः?

Answer (score 0):

Both spellings, "Shantanu" (शंतनुः) and "Shaantanu" (शान्तनुः), are correct and commonly used in different contexts. The variation in spelling can be attributed to differences in transliteration systems and regional pronunciations.

The derivation you provided for the name "Shantanu" (शं तनोति इति शन्तनुः) meaning "He who spreads auspiciousness" is accurate and widely accepted.

As for the name "Shaantanu" (शान्तनुः), while I couldn't find a specific derivation for it, the addition of the long vowel "ा" (aa) in the spelling might suggest an emphasis on peace or tranquility, as "शान्त" (shaanta) means "peaceful" or "calm" in Sanskrit. So, it's possible that "Shaantanu" could be interpreted as "He who is peaceful" or "He who embodies tranquility."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).